# Cudafy chapter 3 example has path issue how to fix?

Tags: cudafy.net

Using Cudafy version 1.29, which can be downloaded from [here](https://cudafy.codeplex.com/)

I am executing the examples that are found in the install folder CudafyV1.29\CudafyByExample\

Specifically, "chapter 3" example that begins line 42 of program.cs calls the following:

```
simple_kernel.Execute();
```

which is this:

```
public static void Execute()
{
    CudafyModule km = CudafyTranslator.Cudafy(); // <--exception thrown!

    GPGPU gpu = CudafyHost.GetDevice(CudafyModes.Target, CudafyModes.DeviceId);
    gpu.LoadModule(km);
    gpu.Launch().thekernel(); // or gpu.Launch(1, 1, "kernel"); 
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
}
```

The indicated line throws this exception:

> Compilation error:  CUDAFYSOURCETEMP.cu
>
> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file. .

Which is immediately obvious that the path has spaces and the programmer did not double quote or use ~ to make it operational.

So, I did not write this code. And I cannot step through the sealed code contained within `CudafyModule km = CudafyTranslator.Cudafy();`In fact I don't even know the full path that is causing the exception, it is cut-off in the exception message.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how to fix this issue?

Update #1: I discovered where CUDAFYSOURCETEMP.cu lives on my computer, here it is:

> C:\Users\humphrt\Desktop\Active Projects\Visual Studio
>   Projects\CudafyV1.29\CudafyByExample\bin\Debug

...I'm still trying to determine what the program is looking for along the path to 'C:\Program~'.

Comment: Perhaps the path is coming from a configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to apply a workaround to bypass this issue. The workaround is to reinstall all components of cudafy in to folders with paths with no ' ' (spaces). My setup looks like the below screenshot. Notice that I also installed the CUDA TOOLKIT from NVIDIA in the same folder - also with no spaces in folder names.

I created a folder named "C:\CUDA" and installed all components within it, here is the folder structure:

[image]